# Set of piecewise continuous real-valued functions on $[0,1] $ is convex

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

I've to proof that the set $E=\{f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\}$ with $f$ a piecewise continuous function is a convex set, for that I have the next tip:

Proof that for every $\lambda\in[0,1]$ exists $a\in[0,1]$ such that
$$\lambda \int_0^1 f(t)dt=\int_0^a f(t)dt$$

Comment: I don't see why you need that integral equation. – If $f$ and $g$ are piecewise continuous on $[0, 1]$ then $\lambda f$ and $(1-\lambda)g$ are also piecewise continuous. So all that remains is to show the sum of two piecewise continuous functions is again piecewise continuous.

Answer (score 0):

from my perspective, because f is piecewise continuous function on [0,1].
(1) let F(x) be the integral of f(x) on [0,x], x≤1，proof that the value of F(x) is intervel [c，d]，c丶d∈R.
（2）for any λ∈[0,1],and F(1)∈[c，d]，let m=λF(1). proof that m∈[c,d].  This is not hard, just find out the possible value range of λF(1) , we can always find out"m" ∈[a,b],m=λF(1).

Comment: Hi, do you know mathjax ?